# Criar links que podem ser copiados ou clicados em Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Criei um script basicamente para realizar o replace de links, removendo alguns caracteres especiais. Está funcional. O problema é apenas a saída de dados, pois estou colocando para apresentar uma label, com o link já sem os caracteres especiais, dessa forma, não é possível copiar o link através da interface. Tem como o resultado desse script ser apresentado de uma forma que seja possível copiar o link, ou clicar? Além disso, é possível que quando o resultado do script for maior que a interface do programa, haja uma quebra de linha automática?

```
from tkinter import *

conversor = Tk()
conversor.title("CONVERSOR DE LINKS")
conversor["bg"] = "white"
conversor.geometry("600x300")


entrada1 = Entry(conversor)
entrada1.place(width= 500, x=50, y=100)

def bt_converter():
    link = (entrada1.get())   
    link = link.replace("%2f", "/")
    link = link.replace("%3f", "?")
    link = link.replace("%3d", "=")
    retorno["text"] = link

btenvio = Button(conversor, width=20, text="Converter", command=bt_converter)
btenvio.place(x=230, y=130)

lb = Label(conversor, text= "DIGITE O LINK")
lb.place(x=180, y=70)

lbretorno = Label(conversor, text="LINK UTILIZÁVEL")
lbretorno.place(x=250, y=180)

retorno = Label(conversor, text="")
retorno.place (width= 500, x=50, y=210)

conversor.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

O próprio tkinter tem um acesso ao Clipboard, que no caso é o Ctrl C. Talvez uma forma seria depois de gerar o texto convertido aparecer um botão que chame uma função que faça a seguinte lógica

```
conversor.clipboard_clear()
conversor.clipboard_append(suaVariavelDeRetorno)
conversor.update() # salva o Ctrl+C mesmo se o programa fecha
```

Comment: Valeu amigo. Criei um botão chamado copiar, defini um método com esse clipboard e funcionou certinho. Criei também outro para acessar, utilizando callback!